# MySQL: Collecting specific data from multiple tables displaying entire database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a database for a final project in my data management course.

I have four tables: customers, parks, trips, and comments

The "customers" table only has two fields that are important: customernumber (auto incremented, primary key) and name.

The "parks" table only has two fields that are important: parknum (auto incremented, primary key) and name.

The "trips" table has three fields, all of which are important: customer (indexed as a foreign key, referencing the customernumber field from the "customers" table), park (indexed as a foreign key, referencing the parknum field in the "parks" table) and date.

The "comments" table has three fields, all of which are important: park (indexed as a foreign key, referencing the parknum field from the "parks" table), customer (indexed as a foreign key, referencing the customernumber field from the "customers" table) and comments.

My goal is to make an SQL query that displays the following fields: customer(name), park(name), trips(date), and comments(comments).

I've tried numerous different queries, and they either display all of the customers, all of the parks, all of the trips and just the comments for that specific park in a repeating order...or it shows zero results

I've done all the research I could between all my textbooks and online sources, but I can't seem to find anything useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a slight issue with the way you've constructed your comments table. The way you currently have it, a customer can have only one comment per park. If a customer visits the same part twice, they can't leave a 2nd comment. Instead you probably want the comment to reference the trip number.

There are a few other things that aren't 100% clear about your question. For example, I assume you want 1 row per trip, not one row per customer, but your question says you want "trips" (plural). Also, it's not clear if comments are manditory or optional and if you want to see a row for a trip if there was no comments.

Assuming you make the suggested change to the comments table, and assuming that comments are optional and you want to see trips even if there wasn't a comment, I think this will do the trick:

```
SELECT customers.name as customer, park.name as park, trips.date as trip, comments
FROM
(customers JOIN trips ON (customers.customer = trips.customer) JOIN parks ON
(parks.parknum = trips.park)) LEFT JOIN comments on (comments.id = trips.comment_id;
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that is has to be for one specific park. I can always add that in with 'WHERE comments.park = 1', correct?
Also, I did make the changes you suggested because yes, you were correct in your assumptions. I'm getting a syntax error at the very end "near LIMIT 0, 30" but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to add that to the WHERE clause. Without seeing your current query it's very hard to say why you're getting a syntax error. You could edit your initial question and post the query along with the error.

Comment: It was a little typo! This solution worked after I made the changes you suggested! Thank you!!